# How to align two TextViews by top line of texts in xml layout?

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I can not align two TextViews in xml layout by top line of texts.
Please do not post solution with margins +/- or with `includeFontPadding`.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST 1"
                android:textSize="64sp"
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST 2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/text1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to use RelativeLayout?

Comment: @TheLibrarian No, but prefer not use support library.

Comment: @Mike M. Good jib. Thank you, but I need for app widget and I can not use it.

Comment: @Mike M. I ask a solution by layout xml, I know how to do this by code. There is more simple way, just use -paint.getFontMetrics().top+paint.getFontMetrics().ascent.

Comment: OK, my apologies. I was not reading the question as asking for a solution only in XML, but rather that you were just having trouble aligning `View`s created in XML.

Comment: @Mike M. Post your answer, I will up vote it.

Comment: It's no problem. :-) I'm not worried about rep.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you wanting an XML solution just because the `LayoutParams` trick doesn't work with `RemoteViews` (until API level 31, anyway)? Or do you just not want a code solution at all? My `setTranslationY` suggestion wouldn't have worked at all, apparently, but you can set negative padding on the `TextView`s through `RemoteViews`, and `setViewPadding()` is available since 16. Ends up something like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWIzM.png. Just thought I'd mention it. Cheers!

Comment: @Mike M. I solved this problem by myself yesterday (ye, I used setViewPadding() ) and by paint.getFontMetrics(). It is works fine. Thank you. There are a lot of important task ignored by Android developer, for example you can not get widget size in pixel directly etc.